# Ruby standalone app deployment/distribution

Tags: ruby, deployment, distribution

What's the best way to distribute a simple command-line Ruby app to clients in a way that would not require them to manually install Ruby and required Gems?

In my understanding this task boils down just to a couple of lines of SH/BAT code that does Ruby/Gems checks and if not found goes on with Ruby installation with [RVM](https://rvm.io).

So do these lines of code exist already somewhere or will I need to write something on my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed to find any way of producing a Ruby cross platform installation.

I've created a [RubyAnywhere](https://github.com/bornmw/RubyAnywhere) script that tries to solve this task.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this project for small scripts in the past, without any issues
http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/rubyscript2exe/

It creates an EXE file out of your ruby script.

If you need something cross-platform, the BAT/sh option is probably best. You could grab RVM, have RVM install ruby, use bundler for your gems, and then launch the script.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I've found is (I believe) releasy: https://github.com/Spooner/releasy